# How to validate forms with a recursive validation function

Tags: python, django, validation, recursion

I'm trying to validate some JSON post data recursively, but having trouble returning error reponses in the "child" calls. Here's a simplified version:

POST data:

```
{
  response_type: "parent",
  subresponses: [
    {
      response_type: "foo",
      value: "something"
    },{
      response_type: "bar",
      value: "something else"
    }
  ]
}
```

The post data can have an arbitrary number of child `subresponses`.

View:

```
def process_response(response):
    forms = {
        'foo': FooForm,
        'bar': BarForm,
    }
    if response.get('response_type') == 'parent':
        for subresponse in response.get('subresponses'):
            self.process_response(subresponse)
    else:
        form = forms[response.get('response_type')](response)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponse(status=200)
        else:
            return JsonResponse({"message": str(form.errors)}, status=400)
```

Of course,  the `process_response` function will throw away the JsonResponse returned by an invalid `subresponse` in a child object; I need to test the return value instead.

I throught about raising an exception in the child and catching it in the parent, but `response_type` may not be `"parent"` - so form validation and exception raising would occur at the "top level" in that scenario. Example:

```
{
  response_type: "bar",
  value: "something"
}
```

Is there a Djangoey way of doing this? And if I'm doing it right, how do I test for returning `JsonResponse(status=400)` if so?

Comment: Can you please give the piece of code at upper level that calls `process_response` ?

Comment: I ask this question because as it is, `process_response` returns `None` if success or a `JsonResponse` if error.

Comment: You're right, in an effort to simplify the code I forgot to return Http200 after saving the form. I've made the edit. `process_resposne` is actually called by `post` after doing some json decoding validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about:

```
def process_response(response):
    forms = {
        'foo': FooForm,
        'bar': BarForm,
    }
    if response.get('response_type') == 'parent':
        for subresponse in response.get('subresponses'):
            result = self.process_response(subresponse)
            if result.status_code != 200:
                return result
    else:
        form = forms[response.get('response_type')](response)
        if not form.is_valid():
            return JsonResponse({"message": str(form.errors)}, status=400)
        form.save()

    return HttpResponse(status=200)
```

The difference being that instead of simply calling `process_response`, we call it, and see if there was a problem.

Comment: Sorry, someone pointed out that I'd forgotten a line (returning Http200 after saving the form). The trouble with your function is that it returns after recursing to the first child (line 10), it won't process subsequent children. This can be changed by testing the `result.status_code` on line 9.

Comment: I updated the answer to reflect the update in your question.